# The entity file has changed to a symbolic link

Tags: macos, zsh, dotfiles

I tried to create a dotfiles directory and manage multiple dot files directly under the home directory.

I accidentally set up a symbolic link to multiple unmanaged dot files.

If you check directly under the home directory, for example

```
$ ls -la .file
> .file @-> /Users/name/dotfiles//.file
```

Like, the real file has been changed to a symbolic link.

And of course, there is no `.file` in `/Users/name/dotfiles//` where it is shown to exist. This is because it was not originally managed within dotfiles, nor moved to dotfiles.

How can I convert multiple dot files that have been changed to symbolic links back to actual files?

Answer (score 0):

If you've clobbered a real file and replaced it with a link going nowhere, there's no easy way to restore it back to its previous form. You can remove the link with `rm <filename>` and recreate the file.